# How to fix PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied in python? (win10)

Tags: python, permission-denied, listdir

I'm trying to resize images in the folder in a folder named "test_09".

```
import PIL
import os
from PIL import Image

f = rb'test_09/'
for folder in os.listdir(f):
    f_folder = f
    for file in os.listdir(f_folder):
        f_img = f_folder + file
        img = Image.open(f_img)
        img = img.resize((300, 400))
        img.save(f_img)
```

The error message:

`Traceback (most recent call last): File "h:\image-resizing.py", line 11, in <module> img = Image.open(f_img) File "C:\Users\usernamee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2878, in open fp = builtins.open(filename, "rb") PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'test_09/L01'`

Before posting this question, I already changed the folder permission to `F` by using `icacls` in window cmd.
Note: All of these mentioned actions were done by using run as administrator.

Comment: Is the image opened by another program?

Comment: Nope. Non of them are opening by the other program.

Comment: Probably unrelated to your problem, but why do you put the directory name in a `bytes` string?

Comment: Whatever you did, the error message still means you don't have access to the file. Can you open it in another program, and see if you get an error for that too? If that's the case, Python isn't part of the problem. (Also, _don't_ run as Administrator.)